# shell command fails when running from crontab

Tags: macos, applescript

[Edit: the original title of this question was "Applescript running from crontab not accessing network?" but having found that the problem is about `PATH`s--not networking, or for that matter Applescript--I have tried to make it more searchable.]

I have a script which I would like to run at 9pm every night that will give me an alert if the Raspberry Pi in my basement is not responding. The script works fine, and tells me my device is up when I run it by hand:

`osascript /users/nat/Code/applescript/ping-pi.scpt`

It also runs from my crontab, but it tells me my device is down... which it isn't.

Here is the crontab line that worked a few minutes ago (for testing, not for 9pm):

`14 15 * * * osascript /users/nat/Code/applescript/ping-pi.scpt`

Here is the script:

```
--based on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3833490
try
    set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 2 <ddns site name here>")
    display dialog "<ddns site name here> is up and running!" with icon note buttons {"OK"} default button 1
on error
    -- if we get here, the ping failed
    display dialog "<ddns site name here> is not responding" with icon caution buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end try
```

The only thing I can think of is that maybe I need to run it as root, but I don't know why that would be.

I can probably get rid of the "set ping to," but I'm just adapting code I found.

Comment: Rule 1 of cron job troubleshooting: log output and errors! Add something like `>>/tmp/ping-pi.log 2>&1` after the command, let it run, then check /tmp/ping-pi.log to see what happened as it runs. When I try it, I get "/path/to/ping-pi.scpt:278:384: execution error: No user interaction allowed. (-1713)" (which is something like what I'd expect, since cron jobs run in the background, and aren't part of the interactive session).

Comment: Rather than `display dialog ...` which requires access to the user's display which `cron` doesn't have as Gordon says, maybe try `display notification "Pi is up/down"` instead as I think that sends a message rather than drawing on the screen for which `cron` lacks permission.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonDavisson and @Mark Setchell, and my apologies for not having replied sooner but I was called away somewhat urgently. Interestingly, the script has no problem displaying a dialogue. It seems to have a problem accessing the network when called as a cron job, in which case it always says that the site is down. When I run from the command line, it gives the correct answer. I did log the output, and just got `«class bhit»:OK`, the acknowledgment that I hit the OK button. Any thoughts about why it would not be able to access the network, or how to fix it?

Comment: This article on "[How to Fix Cron Permission Issues in macOS Big Sur, Catalina, & Mojave](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/)" got me poking around in Settings > Security & Privacy. I added both /usr/sbin/cron and /usr/bin/osascript to the firewall but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that this was not a network-access issue at all, but a `PATH` issue. I [learned in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/429910/102436) that the default path for cron jobs includes just `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. `which ping` told me that I needed `/sbin/ping`, and when I edited the script accordingly, it worked.

I would imagine that this would cause many cron tasks to fail, so I'm a little surprised that it didn't come to my attention sooner.

As I mentioned above, there is no problem putting up a dialog from a cron job, and I will try removing the extra permissions I added, because I'm guessing I don't actually need any special network permissions.